# verify identities $\cos(6x) = 1-2 (2 \sin (x) \cos^2 (x ) + \cos(2x) \sin(x))^2$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

i'm trying to verify this identity and i'm kinda stuck. I will appreciate any help!

$\cos{6x} = 1-2 (2 \sin {x} \cos^2 {x} + \cos{2x} \sin{x})^2$

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $cos(6x) = 1 - 2sin^2(3x) = 1 -  2(sin(2x)cos(x)+sin(x)cos(2x))^2 = 1-2(2sin(x)cos^2(x)+cos(2x)sin(x))^2...$

Comment: thank you so much that helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$. Apply this several times, calculate first $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$, and you can also use the trigonometric Pythagorean theorem ($\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$).

Comment: thank you so much that helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$2\sin x\cos^2x+\cos2x\sin x=\sin x(2\cos^2x+\cos2x)$$
$$=\sin x\{2(1-\sin^2x)+1-2\sin^2x\}=\sin x(3-4\sin^2x)=\sin3x$$

Comment: thank you so much that helped a lot

Comment: @Joey. my pleasure. Nice to hear that